# OxyPlot:Cannot setting Axis values

Tags: axis, oxyplot

I have been tying to set the min and max values of y axis by using properties like  `ActualMinimum` and `ActualMaximum`,but i doesn't work even I set the `MinimumPadding` and `MaximumPadding` to 0. I also tried the Zoom method of axis, it did not work. Sorry that I cannot upload a pic...

Could someone please guide me in this regard ? Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Can you add a link to a pic instead?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/f4jzod321/

Comment: plot1.Model.Axes[0].Zoom(10000,11000)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the properties `AbsoluteMaximum` and `AbsoluteMinimum` to limit the axes to a specific value:

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Left,
            AbsoluteMaximum = 5.5,
            AbsoluteMinimum = 0,
        });
```

In my opinion the properties `ActualMinimum` and `ActualMaximum` are used to limit the axes to an initial value but you are able to zoom out later.

Comment: Thanks!It really works!But I am stil confused about the Zoom method.Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Please check if you point to the right Axes[index]. Please try plot1.Model.Axes[1].Zoom(10000,11000). I guess your Axes[0] is the Abscissa (x) not the Ordinate (y). So your zoom doesn't work. Also always call PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true) outside a constructor to make changes happen on the plot. And please accept answer if it helped you ;).

Comment: Sorry,that was a typing mistake.And I have figured out where the problem was.When I created the OxyPlot object ,I set the PlotType to Cartesian,other than XY,which affected the scale of X axis and Y axis.Thank you again!