# Oxyplot horizontal pan only between the leftmost and rightmost points

Tags: c#, pan, oxyplot

I'm using `Oxyplot` to show graphs. I added the horizontal Pan as following:

```
private void AddHorizonalPanToLinearModel(){
  var b = false;

  GraphModel.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
  {
       if (e.ChangedButton != OxyMouseButton.Left) return;
       b = true;
       CurrentMousePosition = e.Position;
  };

  GraphModel.MouseMove += (s, e) =>
  {
       _xLinearAxis.Pan(CurrentMousePosition, e.Position);

       CurrentMousePosition = e.Position;
       GraphModel.InvalidatePlot(false);
       e.Handled = true;
   };

   GraphModel.MouseUp += (s, e) => b = false;
  }
```

I'm looking for a solution that limits the pan between the leftmost and rightmost x-values but I can't find anything. Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430752/oxyplotcannot-setting-axis-values) the solution is to set `AbsoluteMinimum` and `AbsoluteMaximum` of the axis.